# Elasticsearch filter by matching query in all nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have a problem with filtering elastic documents by nested documents.

In general document has a list of nested assets and each asset have a list of teamIds

Sample cut off document:

```
{
   "assets":[
      {
         "id":100,
         "teams":[
            1
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":101,
         "teams":[
            4,
            3
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected result is to get root document where all assets have at least one matching team

I've tried:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "nested": {
                                                "path": "assets",
                                                "query": {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "assets.teams": [
                                                            1
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": [
                                        {
                                            "nested": {
                                                "path": "assets",
                                                "query": {
                                                    "bool": {
                                                        "must": [
                                                            {
                                                                "exists": {
                                                                    "field": "assets"
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 999
}
```

Unfortunately this query return document. In this case I do expect it returns document if query contains ids like [1,3], [1,4] or [1,3,4]

Thanks in advance

Comment: your query should be working. Can you provide more details as which document is getting missed on which query. Can you also add your mapping

Comment: Assets are marked as nested. 
With this query I do not expect to get document from sample but I'm getting it in result.
I would like to get only documents where all assets have at least one matching team from query array

Comment: {
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "assets":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "id":{
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "teams":{
                  "type":"long"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

Comment: If issue is that you need only matched nested documents , then you need to add inner_hits https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html  to nested query.

Comment: I need root document :) only if all nested documents match query

Answer (score 0):

To find a document where all nested documents contain any of given terms

`````
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "assets",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "assets.teams": [
                        "1"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
````

In the above, nested query returns documents where a nested document does not contain any of given term, then outer must_not excludes those documents.
In other words first find documents where a nested document doesnot contain given term and then exclude those documents.

If you want to include documents where teams field is not present use below

````
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "assets",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "assets.teams"
                    }
                  }
                ], 
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "assets.teams": [
                        "1"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

````
`````